# Where do I get the standard, tiny Facebook and Twitter icons?

Tags: images, facebook, twitter

I've seen a lot of sites with tiny 't' and 'f' logos for Facebook and Twitter.  They're pretty common, but the only images I can find available are for paid icon sets.

Are people really using custom icons for these or are Facebook and Twitter offering official ones somewhere on their websites?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First few Google hits for *Twitter logo* and *Facebook logo* are successful:

- [Facebook logos](http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php)
- [Twitter logos](http://twitter.com/about/resources/logos)

The Twitter "t" should not be used anymore and be replaced with the bird. Like it or not, it's the new official one.

Comment: Thanks!  Can't believe I didn't find these links in my searches, but this is exactly what I'm looking for.